# How to use ngx permission to protect admin Page in angular?

Tags: angular

I have admin page Url and i want to protect it but i don't know how to use ngx-permissions in this case as i am new in angular.so can anyone please tell me how can i protect my admin page using angular.
 Here is my redirecting code written below:

```
if(this.userId === this.adminId){
              this.admin=true;
              this.router.navigate(['/admin']); }
            else{
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
```

I am using AdminId and if it is matched with userId then i am redirecting  the router to admin page.I don't know is it the only way to redirecting?So please tell also how can i navigate the router to admin page securely? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Check upon guards and `canActivate` in route configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use guards with angular router, using the param `canActivate` in your routes, something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [      
{ path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
];
```

And the AdminGuard file can be:

**Important:** You just need to pass your params (userId and adminId) in the page url.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public router: Router
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ) {
    const { userId, adminId } = route.queryParams;
    if (userId === adminId) {
      // this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
      return true; // This line allows user access to admin route
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is giving error that : error TS2365: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'Params'.

Comment: where to pass the queryparams , in the admin Path or somewhere else I don't know

Comment: Query params are params in the URL, is like: `example.com/admin?userId=john&adminId=mike`.

So userId has the value 'john' and adminId has the value 'mike'.

If you need to navigate from the code and send params to the route you can use the anguar router. This is an example:

`this.router.navigate(['admin'], { queryParams: { userId: 'john', adminId: 'mike' } } )`

With this line you got the same result than use the url directly